# In ASP.NET MVC 5, after i apply migrations for a change in MODEL class ,will it change my View .cshtml file as well?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I applied some changes in my student.cs (model) file and updated the database through migrations. But i need to see those changes in my view as well. Is it going to appear itself or do i need to a manually add those newly added values?

Comment: Are you talking about scaffolding or some auto-generated view or something? Someone will certainly ask for a code sample because, if you're talking about a regular view that you code yourself, the answer is probably no.

Comment: yes, at the first place i used scaffolding. and now after updating the database i can't find those required changes in my database! Should i manually add them now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrations is not going to generate any code for you. If you're model changed, then Visual Studio's "Auto Rename" feature can update existing properties (provided you chose to do so). But other than, its not going to scaffold newer properties in the View automatically.